# Showing that the symmetry group of a circle is non-abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having a few problems showing the circle in part b) is non-abelian.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the hint? If so, what are you having trouble with precisely?

Comment: Did you try to do what is outlined in green? (Either in your mind, or make a model out of paper and do what is hinted at.)

Comment: No I understand it in principle it's just writing it down that's the issue

Comment: All you have to do is write down two specific elements and prove they do not commute.

Comment: @usainlightning It may be easier to compute the matrices of a rotation and a reflection and then show that the order of multiplication matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you conjugate a reflection with a rotation, the result is a reflection along the rotated axis.